# Gitlab LDAP with SASL

Tags: ldap, gitlab

I'm trying to configure Gitlab 10.0.2 to use LDAP authentication. I cannot use TLS, so I was hoping to use SASL DIGEST-MD5 to provide better security than cleartext. The Gitlab documentation [seems to suggest that this is possible](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/auth/ldap.html#tls-client-authentication) (emphasis mine):

> You should disable anonymous LDAP authentication and enable simple **or SASL authentication**.

However, it does not provide any guidance on how to configure a SASL bind. I've tried setting the `try_sasl` and `sasl_mechanisms` configuration keys mentioned in [the omniauth-ldap README](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omniauth-ldap/blob/master/README.md), but I've verified with Wireshark that a simple bind is still being used instead of DIGEST-MD5.

The relevant section from my gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true

###! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
  main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
    label: 'LDAP'
    host: 'my-ldap.example.com'
    port: 389
    uid: 'sAMAccountName'
    bind_dn: 'my-username'
    password: 'my-password'
    encryption: 'plain' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
    verify_certificates: true
    ca_file: ''
    ssl_version: ''
    active_directory: true
    try_sasl: true
    sasl_mechanisms: 'DIGEST-MD5'
    allow_username_or_email_login: false
    block_auto_created_users: false
    base: ''
    user_filter: ''
    attributes:
      username:   'sAMAccountName'
      email:      'mail'
      name:       'displayName'
      first_name: 'givenName'
      last_name:  'sn'
    ## EE only
    group_base: ''
    admin_group: ''
    sync_ssh_keys: false
EOS
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, but only by patching the Gitlab install. So, be forewarned: **Here there be dragons**

## Patch

### /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true

###! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
  main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
    label: 'LDAP'
    host: 'my-ldap.example.com'
    port: 389
    uid: 'sAMAccountName'
    bind_dn: 'my-username'
    bind_target: 'userPrincipalName'
    password: 'my-password'
    encryption: 'plain' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
    verify_certificates: true
    ca_file: ''
    ssl_version: ''
    active_directory: true
    try_sasl: true
    sasl_mechanisms: ['DIGEST-MD5']
    sasl_realm: 'Digest'
    allow_username_or_email_login: false
    block_auto_created_users: false
    base: ''
    user_filter: ''
    attributes:
      username:   'sAMAccountName'
      email:      'mail'
      name:       'displayName'
      first_name: 'givenName'
      last_name:  'sn'
    ## EE only
    group_base: ''
    admin_group: ''
    sync_ssh_keys: false
EOS
```

### /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/ldap/config.rb

Patch `omniauth_options` to pass through configuration parameters

```
def omniauth_options
  opts = base_options.merge(
    base: base,
    encryption: options['encryption'],
    filter: omniauth_user_filter,
    name_proc: name_proc,
    disable_verify_certificates: !options['verify_certificates']
  )

  if has_auth?
    opts.merge!(
      bind_dn: options['bind_dn'],
      password: options['password']
    )
  end

  opts[:ca_file] = options['ca_file'] if options['ca_file'].present?
  opts[:ssl_version] = options['ssl_version'] if options['ssl_version'].present?
  opts[:try_sasl] = options['try_sasl'] if options['try_sasl'].present?
  opts[:sasl_mechanisms] = options['sasl_mechanisms'] if options['sasl_mechanisms'].present?
  opts[:bind_target] = options['bind_target'] if options['bind_target'].present?
  opts[:sasl_digest_uri] = options['sasl_digest_uri'] if options['sasl_digest_uri'].present?
  opts[:sasl_realm] = options['sasl_realm'] if options['sasl_realm'].present?

  opts
end
```

### /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pyu-ruby-sasl-0.0.3.3/lib/sasl/digest_md5.rb

Patch `receive` to use realm from configuration in preference to realm from server challenge (this is necessary for authentication against active directory)

```
response['realm'] = preferences.realm || c['realm']
```

### /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gitlab_omniauth-ldap-2.0.4/lib/omniauth-ldap/adaptor.rb

Modify valid configuration keys

```
VALID_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION_KEYS = [
  :hosts, :host, :port, :encryption, :disable_verify_certificates, :bind_dn, :password, :try_sasl,
  :sasl_mechanisms, :bind_target, :uid, :base, :allow_anonymous, :filter, :ca_file, :ssl_version,
  :sasl_digest_uri, :sasl_realm,

  # Deprecated
  :method
]
```

In `initialize`, set 'dn' as default bind target

```
@configuration[:bind_target] ||= :dn
```

Modify `bind_as` to fix checking for SASL configuration key and to use bind target

```
def bind_as(args = {})
  result = false
  @connection.open do |me|
    rs = me.search args
    if rs and rs.first and user = rs.first.first(@bind_target).to_s
      password = args[:password]
      password = password.call if password.respond_to?(:call)
      if @bind_method == :sasl
      result = rs.first if me.bind(sasl_auths({:username => user, :password => password}).first)
      else
      result = rs.first if me.bind(:method => :simple, :username => user,
                          :password => password)
      end
    end
  end
  result
end
```

I don't know ruby well, but from what I can tell the unpatched version is broken and will always use a simple bind

```
(Unpatched)
method = args[:method] || @method
password = password.call if password.respond_to?(:call)
if method == 'sasl'
```

Patch `sasl_bind_setup_digest_md5` to pass realm property to SASL

```
def sasl_bind_setup_digest_md5(options)
  bind_dn = options[:username]
  digest_uri = options[:digest_uri] || @sasl_digest_uri || "ldap/#{@host}"
  realm = options[:realm] || @sasl_realm || @host
  initial_credential = ""
  challenge_response = Proc.new do |cred|
    pref = SASL::Preferences.new :digest_uri => digest_uri, :realm => realm, :username => bind_dn, :has_password? => true, :password => options[:password]
    sasl = SASL.new("DIGEST-MD5", pref)
    response = sasl.receive("challenge", cred)
    response[1]
  end
  [initial_credential, challenge_response]
end
```

## Results

```
 tshark -i any -f "tcp port 389" -Y "ldap" -T text
  4 0.000627931  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 96 bindRequest(1) "<ROOT>" [Malformed Packet]
  5 0.001160032  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 323 bindResponse(1) saslBindInProgress
  7 0.001826383  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 432 bindRequest(1) "<ROOT>" sasl
  8 0.005544029  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 132 bindResponse(1) success
  9 0.005872822  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 264 searchRequest(2) "<ROOT>" baseObject
 11 0.006116795  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 253 searchResEntry(2) "<ROOT>"
 13 0.006579437  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 175 searchRequest(3) "*************" wholeSubtree
 17 0.008437742  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 584 searchResEntry(3) "CN=*******************************************"
 18 0.009509758  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 96 bindRequest(4) "<ROOT>" [Malformed Packet]
 19 0.009794269  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 323 bindResponse(4) saslBindInProgress
 20 0.010279312  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 431 bindRequest(4) "<ROOT>" sasl
 21 0.013109814  **.**.**.** -> **.**.**.**  LDAP 132 bindResponse(4) success
```